# Problem in saving extended User Model. type object 'UserProfile' has no attribute 'USERNAME_FIELD'?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I am trying to create a model UserProfile by extending it from Django's built in User model. After filling out the form the data should be saved in UserProfile model. It's just not happening

Initially, the data was only saved in User model but not in UserProfile model. I applied some recommended solutions from the web but now I cannot even fill up the form. On prompting to/register, I get an error saying,

**type object 'UserProfile' has no attribute 'USERNAME_FIELD'**

```
#models.py

    from django.db import models
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User

    class UserProfile(models.Model):
        user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        email = models.EmailField( max_length=254)
        country = models.CharField( max_length=50)



#forms.py
    from django import forms
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
    from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
    from .models import UserProfile

    class RegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):

        class Meta:
            model = UserProfile
            fields = ['email', 'country']



#views.py
    from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
    from django.http import HttpResponse
    from .forms import RegistrationForm
    from .models import UserProfile 
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User

    def home(request):
         return render(request , 'guide/index.html')

    def register(request):

         if request.method=='POST':
              form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
              if form.is_valid():
                   u= form.save(commit=False)
                   u.user = request.user
                   u.save()

                   return redirect('home')

         else:
              form=RegistrationForm()          
         return render(request, 'guide/register.html', {'form':form})
```

I want the code to run and save the data to UserProfile model, but the page says that UserProfile has no attribute 'USERNAME_FIELD'

Comment: Did you applied `makemigrations` and then `migrate`

Comment: I'm pretty sure, I did that.